# Galois cohomology of cyclotomic extension

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, deformation-theory, galois-representations, galois-cohomology

Let $K$ be a complete discrete valuation ring with algebraically closed residue field $F$ of characteristic $p > 0$. Suppose ${\Bbb Q}_p \subset K$ and the absolute ramification index v$_{\pi_K}(p) = e_K < \infty$.

Suppose that $\mu_p \in K$ and set $K_{\infty} \colon= K(\zeta_{p^{\infty}})$, which is the cyclotomic ${\Bbb Z}_p$-extension of $K$.

### Q. How can I prove $H^1({\mathrm{Gal}}(K_{\infty}/K), H^1(K_{\infty}, \mu_p)) = 0$

Comment: Use Theorem $1.11$ of https://arxiv.org/pdf/1111.4914.pdf and the Artin-Schreier exact sequence on the tilted side.

Comment: Thanks. So you mean that $H^1(K_{\infty}, \mu_p) \cong H^1(F, \Z/p) = {\mathrm{Hom}}({\mathrm{Gal}}(\overline{F}/F),{\Bbb Z}/p) = 0$. Right?